# Stack search causes stack overflow

Tags: java, queue, stack-overflow

I am trying to search a "hand of cards" (a queue) by inputting a search card, comparing the values (colour and rank) of the search card to the current card in the hand, and if a match is found, outputting the matching card and changing the "mood" of the current player. If no match is found and the entire hand has not been searched, then the current card is dequeued, enqueued at the back of the hand, and the method is run again. If the entire hand has been searched (leading back to the first card of the hand), then a "dummy card" is to be returned.
My problem is that, if a matching card is not found, then a StackOverflowError appears. I do not know where this is coming from, but I presume it has to do with the enqueuing/dequeuing of the cards and recursiveness of the method (toward the end). If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. If you need more code or more info, just ask.

NEW CODE:

```
(at top of class)
int counter = 1;

....

/**
 * Method that checks a player's hand for matching cards
 * @param searchCard card to search for in player's hand
 * @return card in player's hand if found, dummy card otherwise
 */
public UnoCard getMatch(UnoCard searchCard) {
    UnoCard foundCard;
    UnoCard currentCard = cards.first();
    UnoCard noCard = new UnoCard('N', 0);

    //check if colours of cards match
    if (currentCard.getColour() == searchCard.getColour()) {
        //set mood, remove card from hand, and return matching card
        setMood("Colour");
        foundCard = currentCard;
        cards.dequeue();
        return foundCard;
    //check if ranks of cards match
    } else if (currentCard.getRank() == searchCard.getRank()) {
        //set mood, remove card from hand, and return matching card
        setMood("Rank");            
        foundCard = currentCard;
        cards.dequeue();
        return foundCard;
    //if no match is found
    } else {
        //check if end of hand has been reached
        if (counter == cards.size()) {
            //set mood and return dummy card
            setMood("No match");
            counter = 1;
            return noCard;
        } else {
            //place card at back of hand and search again with next card in hand
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Counter is: " + counter);
            cards.dequeue();
            cards.enqueue(currentCard);
            return getMatch(searchCard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `counter` should not be a method parameter instead of a method variable?

Comment: Why don't you use a List (or even a Set if the order doesn't matter), and its `contains()` and `remove()` methods?

Comment: `counter` is used as a representation of which card in the hand the method is currently on. When the method is run, it's initialized to 1 (for the first card). I don't think it should be a parameter because it has to start off the same way every time the method is called. We cannot use lists, sorry.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I think you've got it. You should answer. Counter needs to be a class member. Currently you are looping through the hand over and over, as counter is set to 1 every time you recursively call the function.

Comment: @lollercopter Think it through. If you set counter to 1 every time you call search, and you only ever add 1 to inside the function, how will it ever reach (7/9/whatever)?

Comment: Oh... I understand completely now. Thank you for the help, I completely missed such a small, stupid error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should have something like this:

```
public UnoCard getMatch(UnoCard searchCard) {
    return getMatch(searchCard, 0);
}

private UnoCard getMatch(UnoCard searchCard, int counter) {
    //int counter = 0
    ... the rest of your code

    // Recursion at the end
    getMatch(searchCard, counter);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not quite what I expected, but there are many ways to fix the problem ;)

Comment: Oh, there are probably better ways to handle this, but this is one of the minimal modification we can have. Without the rest of the code, it is hard to say what to do.

Comment: Alright, I have my corrected code in my top post. I tried to avoid making another method just to see if it would work. However, after tracing the counter and entering the no match case, the counter increases to around 8500 before an overflow occurs. How is the test to check if `counter = cards.size()` (the size of the hand) not working?

Comment: Are `currentCard.getColour()` and `currentCard.getRank()` returning objects that are not enum objects? If so, you need to use `.equals()` to compare and not `==`

Comment: Your solution may work but is more likely to break if you forget to reset your counter. Without the whole code, we cannot help you much. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I tried `.equals()`, but that did not work. `colour` is a char, and `rank` is an int. The comparisons work fine, but the no match case is where everything fails. Would the counter not reset when no match is found, where it says `counter = 1;`? What other code would you like to see, if it helps?

Comment: I think that actually, the counter should be init to 0 (if there are no cards, then it should end directly). Also, if you want to be more robust, you could use counter>=cards.size() as stop-condition

Comment: Setting `counter = 0;` and `counter >= cards.size();` worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!